# How can I initialize a class property that depends on an initializer argument as well as `self`?

Tags: swift

I am a new Swift developer. Is there a proper pattern for initializing a class variable whose initializer requires a reference to `self`?

Example code:

```
class Consumer
{
    var supplier: Supplier;

    init(observer: Observer)
    {
        // error: 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized
        self.supplier = Supplier(observer: observer, consumer: self);
    }
}

class Observer {}

class Supplier
{
    init(observer: Observer, consumer: Consumer) {/*do init*/}
}
```

I can make the property an explicitly unwrapped optional, but this feels wrong to me because I don't want to incur the costs related to optionals (this variable will be accessed in a tight loop). Is this assumption wrong? Do explicitly unwrapped optionals provide performance comparable to regular a `var` or are they still checked on access?

```
class Consumer
{
    var supplier: Supplier!; // explicitly unwrapped Optional

    init(observer: Observer)
    {
        /*
        pro: problem solved
        con?: accessing supplier incurs the costs of accessing an Optional?
        */
        self.supplier = Supplier(observer: observer, consumer: self);
    }
}

/*other classes*/
```

I can have an extra variable to first initialize the class and then a lazy variable to be able to use `self`, but then I'm storing an extra variable in the class that isn't really ever needed after initialization.

```
class Consumer
{
    var observer: Observer; // never used elsewhere after initialization
    lazy var supplier: Supplier = Supplier(observer: observer, consumer: self);

    init(observer: Observer)
    {
        /*
        pro: problem solved
        con: small memory overhead
        */
        self.observer = observer;
    }
}

/*other classes*/
```

**NOTE:** I am not looking for advice on reference dependency cycles, just on the stated problem.

Comment: Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals don't have extra cost for access.

Comment: Also, both `Consumer` or `Supplier` shouldn't store strong links to each other. Check if they do. Otherwise you gonna have memory leak. If they do, you should change one of them to `weak`, and `weak` supposed to be `Optional`.

Comment: It's impossible to create a chain like this (Consumer object holds a supplier, which references the consumer) without mutability. One object has to be made first (with a `nil` counterpart), and another has to be made second (referencing the first), after which the first object could be set to reference the second.

Comment: With property wrappers, you can capture this delayed initialization pattern in a [property wrapper](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md#delayed-initialization)

Comment: @user28434 Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals are still Optionals with some additional checks behind the scenes according to `Implicit Unwrapping is Part of a Declaration` in https://swift.org/blog/iuo/ ; I can't seem to find any search results that compare performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative is to declare `consumer` in `Supplier`as  `weak optional` to avoid a retain cycle (`Consumer` holds a strong reference to `Supplier` and vice versa)

```
class Consumer
{
    let supplier: Supplier

    init(observer: Observer)
    {
        self.supplier = Supplier(observer: observer)
        supplier.consumer = self
    }
}

class Observer {}

class Supplier
{
    let observer : Observer
    weak var consumer : Consumer?

    init(observer: Observer, consumer: Consumer? = nil) {
        self.observer = observer
        self.consumer = consumer
    }
}
```

And this is Swift: No trailing semicolons.